# Behavior from module SessionsHelper is not included in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to add sessions to my rails app and I have class `SessionManager` which is responsible for handling session related tasks

```
class SessionManager
  include SessionsHelper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    return false if current_user.nil? 
    true
  end
end
```

as you can see I include `SessionsHelper` in order to use `session` method  to put some data into session, but when I try to use this code I get back:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for <SessionManager:0xa790cfc>
```

What do I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your SessionsHelper module looks like, but you may want to look at using self.included. This is sometimes known as a "mixin".

I believe structuring your module similar to this should help you:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do

      def session
        # ...
      end

    end
  end
end
```

More info on included: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included